# how perform zooming inside canvas image and the zooming should be centralized

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

```
 <div id="panId" class="moveAble">

    <canvas id="canvas" class="mg_image">

       <img name="imageName2" id="mainImage" class="imagepics" 
              *ngIf="showImage" 

              src="{{imageVisible ? droppedImage: firtsImageToBind}}">


            </canvas>
        </div>
```

My typescript code is given below.

```
 forActivateZooming(event: MouseEvent) {

    document.getElementById('panId').style.cursor = "zoom-in";

    this.showImage = true;
    this.imageVisible = false;






    var zoomIntensity = 5;

    var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("canvas");


    var image = document.getElementById("mainImage");


    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.moveTo(0, 0);


    var img = document.getElementById("mainImage");

    var srcOfImg = img.attributes.getNamedItem('src').value;




    var width = 2000;
    var height = 2000;

    var scale = 10;
    var originx = 0;
    var originy = 0;
    var visibleWidth = width;
    var visibleHeight = height;

    var count = 10;

    canvas.onmousewheel = function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Get mouse offset.
        //   var mousex = event.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        //   var mousey = event.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var mousex = event.clientX - offset.left;
        var mousey = event.clientY - offset.top;


        // Normalize wheel to +1 or -1.
        var wheel = event.wheelDelta / 120;

        // Compute zoom factor.
        var zoom = Math.exp(wheel * zoomIntensity);

        // Translate so the visible origin is at the context's origin.
        context.translate(originx, originy);

        // Compute the new visible origin. Originally the mouse is at a
        // distance mouse/scale from the corner, we want the point under
        // the mouse to remain in the same place after the zoom, but this
        // is at mouse/new_scale away from the corner. Therefore we need to
        // shift the origin (coordinates of the corner) to account for this.
        originx -= mousex / (scale * zoom) - mousex / scale;
        originy -= mousey / (scale * zoom) - mousey / scale;

        // alert(originx);
        // alert(originy);

        // alert(zoom);

        // Scale it (centered around the origin due to the trasnslate above).
        context.scale(originx, originy);
        // Offset the visible origin to it's proper position.
        context.translate(-originx, -originy);

        var ratio = 5;
        var vpx = 0;
        var vpy = 0;
        var vpw = window.innerWidth;
        var vph = window.innerHeight;

        var orig_width = 2000;
        var orig_height = 2000;

        //var width = 4000
        //var height = 4000














        if (event.wheelDelta >= 120) {



            canvas.width = canvas.width * ratio;

            canvas.height = canvas.height * ratio;

            // var u_top = $('.mg-image').offset().top;
            // var u_left = $('.mg-image').offset().left;
            // alert(u_top);
            // alert(u_left);

            //  $('.mg-image').css('left', '10%');
            //  $('.mg-image').css('top', '10%');

            //var ratio = image.clientHeight / image.clientWidth;
            var curLeft = image.offsetLeft;
            // alert(curLeft);
            var curTop = image.offsetTop;
            // alert(curTop);

            // $('.mg_image').css({
            //     height: image.clientHeight + (20 * ratio),
            //     width: image.clientWidth + (20 * ratio),
            //     left: curLeft - ((20 * ratio) / 2),
            //     top: curTop - ((20 * ratio) / 2)
            // });


            // zoom center point
            // var targetX = event.clientX || (vpw / 2);
            // var targetY = event.clientY || (vph / 2);

            // // percentages from side
            // var pX = ((vpx * -1) + targetX) * 100 / width;
            // var pY = ((vpy * -1) + targetY) * 100 / height;

            // // translate view back to center point
            // var x = ((width * pX / 100) - targetX);
            // var y = ((height * pY / 100) - targetY);


            // $('.mg_image').css({
            //     // height: image.clientHeight + (20 * ratio),
            //     //  width: image.clientWidth + (20 * ratio),
            //     left: curLeft - ((20 * ratio) / 2),
            //     top: curTop - ((20 * ratio) / 2)
            // });

            // var position = $('.mg_image').position();

            // //alert(position.left);
            // //alert(position.top);
            // var newLeft = position.left - 10;
            // var newTop = position.top - 10;


            // canvas.style.top = newLeft + '0%';
            // canvas.style.left = newTop + '0%';


            // $('#canvas').css({
            //     height: offsetHeightvalue - 5,
            //     width: offsetWidthvalue - 5,
            //     left: offsetLeftvalue - 5,
            //     top: offsetTopvalue - 5
            // });

            //  resizeCall(++count);

        }
        else if (event.wheelDelta <= -120) {

           // canvas.width = canvas.width / ratio;

           // canvas.height = canvas.height / ratio;



            // var u_top = $('.mg-image').offset().top;
            // var u_left = $('.mg-image').offset().left;


            // alert(u_top);
            // alert(u_left);
            // $('.mg-image').css('left', u_left--);
            // $('.mg-image').css('top', u_top--);


            // var ratio = image.clientHeight / image.clientWidth;
            var curLeft = image.offsetLeft;
            // alert(curLeft);
            var curTop = image.offsetTop;
            // alert(curTop);



            var offsetLeftvalue = canvas.offsetLeft;
            var offsetTopvalue = canvas.offsetTop;
            var offsetHeightvalue = canvas.offsetHeight;
            var offsetWidthvalue = canvas.offsetWidth;


            canvas.width;
            canvas.height;

            // $('#canvas').css({
            //     align: offsetHeightvalue - 5,
            //     width: offsetWidthvalue - 5,
            //     left: offsetLeftvalue - 5,
            //     top: offsetTopvalue - 5
            // });

            // $('.mg_image').css({
            //     height: image.clientHeight + (20 * ratio),
            //     width: image.clientWidth + (20 * ratio),
            //     left: curLeft - ((20 * ratio) / 2),
            //     top: curTop - ((20 * ratio) / 2)
            // });

            // // zoom center point
            // var targetX = event.clientX || (vpw / 2);
            // var targetY = event.clientY || (vph / 2);

            // // percentages from side
            // var pX = ((vpx * -1) + targetX) * 100 / width;
            // var pY = ((vpy * -1) + targetY) * 100 / height;

            // // translate view back to center point
            // var x = ((width * pX / 100) - targetX);
            // var y = ((height * pY / 100) - targetY);


            // $('.mg_image').css({
            //     // height: image.clientHeight + (20 * ratio),
            //     //   width: image.clientWidth + (20 * ratio),
            //     left: curLeft - ((20 * ratio) / 2),
            //     top: curTop - ((20 * ratio) / 2)
            // });


            //alert(position.left);
            //alert(position.top);

            // var position = $('.mg_image').position();
            // var newLeft = position.left - 10;
            // var newTop = position.top - 10;


            // canvas.style.top = newLeft + '0%';
            // canvas.style.left = newTop + '0%';

            //  resizeCall(--count);
            return false;
        }



    }

    function resizeCall(c: any) {

        var img = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('mainImage');


        var sizeWidth = context.canvas.clientWidth;
        var sizeHeight = context.canvas.clientHeight;

        //  var x = event.pageX;
        //  var y = event.pageY;

        // var width = canvas.width;
        // var height = canvas.height;

        //context.scale(x + width / 2, y + height / 2);




        // alert(c);




        // img.style.zoom = c + '0%';


        // canvas.width = 2000;
        //  canvas.height = 2000;

        // alert(canvas.getBoundingClientRect());

        // var context = canvas.getContext("2d");


        // var ratio = canvas.height / canvas.width;
        // var curLeft = canvas.offsetLeft;
        // //alert(curLeft);
        // var curTop = canvas.offsetTop;
        // // alert(curTop);

        // $('.mg_image').css({
        //     //  height: canvas.height + (20 * ratio),
        //     //  width: canvas.width + (20 * ratio),
        //     left: curLeft - ((50 * ratio) / 2),
        //     top: curTop - ((50 * ratio) / 2)
        // });

        //context.moveTo(0, 0);

        canvas.style.zoom = c + '0%';





        // canvas.style.left = c  ;
        // canvas.style.top = c ;
        //canvas.width = sizeWidth + c;

        //  canvas.height = sizeHeight +c;


        //  img.width =  img.width + c;
        //  img.height =  img.height + c;

        //alert(img.width);
        //alert(img.height);


        // // this.url = 'http://mediotrenderingservice-dev.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/wado?requestType=wado&studyUID=1&seriesUID=46&ObjectUID=370&rows=' + this.clientX + '&columns=' + this.clientY;
        // this.url = 'http://mediotrenderservice-env.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/wado?requestType=wado&studyUID=65&seriesUID=46&ObjectUID=' + this.currentObjectId.toString() + '&rows=' + rows + '&columns=' + columns;
        // // http://mediotrenderservice-env.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/wado?requestType=wado&studyUID=65&seriesUID=46&ObjectUID=372&rows=512&columns=512
        // console.log(this.url);

        // this.http.get(this.url)

        //     .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        //     .subscribe(data => {
        //         console.log(data);

        //         this.firtsImageToBind = "";
        //         this.showImage = true;

        //         this.imageVisible = false;
        //         // this.firtsImageToBind = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data.DCMImageBuffer;



        //         var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("canvas");

        //         canvas.width = 2000;
        //         canvas.height = 2000;

        //         var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        //         var img = new Image();
        //         img.onload = function () {

        //             var width = rows;
        //             var height = columns;

        //             context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
        //         }
        //         //  img.width = 100;
        //         //  img.height = 100;
        //         this.firtsImageToBind = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data.DCMImageBuffer;

        //         img.src = this.firtsImageToBind;


        //         console.log(this.firtsImageToBind);

        //     }, (err) => console.error(err),
        //     () => console.log('done')
        //     );


    }

    // document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', moveObject,false);



    // document.onmousewheel = moveObject;



    // function moveObject(event: any) {

    //     var delta = 0;

    //     if (!event) event = window.event;

    //     // normalize the delta

    //     if (event.wheelDelta) {

    //         // IE and Opera

    //         delta = event.wheelDelta / 60;

    //     } else if (event.detail) {

    //         // W3C

    //         delta = -event.detail / 2;

    //     }

    //     var currPos = document.getElementById('mainImage').offsetTop;

    //     //calculating the next position of the object

    //     currPos = currPos - (delta * 10);

    //     //moving the position of the object

    //     document.getElementById('mainImage').style.top = currPos + "px";

    //     document.getElementById('mainImage').innerHTML //code below
    //         = event.wheelDelta + ":" + event.detail;

    // }


    // $(document).ready(function () {
    //     $("#panId").mouseup(function () {

    //         // $("#mainImage").focus({ "outline": "none" });
    //         $("#mainImage").focus(function () {
    //             $("#mainImage").css("outline", "none");
    //         });
    //     });
    //     $("#panId").mousedown(function () {


    //         var target = document.getElementById('mainImage');

    //         var height = target.clientHeight;
    //         var width = target.clientWidth;

    //         height = height + 5;
    //         width = width + 5;

    //         $("#mainImage").css({ "height": height, "width": width });

    //         this.url = 'http://mediotrenderservice-env.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/wado?requestType=wado&studyUID=65&seriesUID=46&ObjectUID=' + this.currentObjectId.toString() + '&rows=' + width + '&columns=' + height;
    //         console.log(this.url);

    //         //  this.http.get(this.url)

    //         //     .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    //         //     .subscribe(data => {
    //         //         console.log(data);

    //         //         this.firtsImageToBind = "";
    //         //         this.showImage = true;

    //         //         this.imageVisible = false;
    //         //         this.firtsImageToBind = 'data:image/png;base64,' + data.DCMImageBuffer;


    //         //         console.log(this.firtsImageToBind);




    //         //     }, (err) => console.error(err),
    //         //     () => console.log('done')
    //         //     );



    //     });
    // });


}
```

My requirement is image zooming (in centralized zooming).

Please provide any solution

Comment: please define centralized zooming. preferably with images of what you wish to happen.

Comment: I assume they mean the zoom is centered on the centerpoint of the canvas.

Comment: Yes you are write...

Comment: During zooming time should maintain aspect ratio of screen.

Comment: Please provide any idea....!!!